# Save a single subgraph/signature in existing TFLite model as a new TFLite model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a saved tflite model: `model.tflite`

I can load the model using: `interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="model.tflite")`

This model has multiple subgraphs (or 'signatures' as they are called in tflite). I can extract 1 signature as a callable function like: `subgraph = interpreter.get_signature_runner("input_1")`. Then I can call it like this: `subgraph(input_0=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]), input_1=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]))` which gives the correct output.

But how can I save this signature as a new tflite model with only 1 subgraph? For my use case I only need this one signature and need the tflite model to only have 1 subgraph.